# How to give the user the choice between Gallery and Camera in ImagePicker

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I am using ImagePicker in a flutter app, but we should specify the source of the Image.
How can I let the choice to the user?

```dart
File? selectedImage;

  getImage() async {
    XFile? file = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    selectedImage = File(file!.path);
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show a dialog for to choose option.

```dart
getImage() async {
  bool? isCamera = await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            },
            child: Text("Camera"),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
            },
            child: Text("gallery "),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );

  if (isCamera == null) return;

  XFile? file = await ImagePicker()
      .pickImage(source: isCamera ? ImageSource.camera : ImageSource.gallery);
  selectedImage = File(file!.path);
  setState(() {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two Text one for gallery and one for Camera and on thier onTap() you should pass a function which will be like

```dart
void imageGalleryBottomSheet(
      {BuildContext context,
      VoidCallback onCameraTap,
      VoidCallback onGalleryTap}) {
//your code logic

}
```